# CSS to hide all theads other than first table

Tags: css

I'm trying to hide all `<thead></thead>` except first table by using the following CSS rule:

```css
@media screen {
  .container>table:not(:first-child)>thead {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Table Caption</div>
  <table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
  <div>Table Caption</div>
  <table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
  <div>Table Caption</div>
  <table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

But this rule hides all `<thead></thead>`. Any help?

Comment: Your CSS works as you say you want it to for me in both Chrome on Windows and Firefox on Windows.  Are you doing anything else? What is your context?

Comment: @petern0691 I've updated the question. This is the actual markup.

Comment: @s.k.paul You are missing some content in the `<thead>` so it will not show anything. If you have some content, please add it to the snippet.

Comment: As F. Müller states, you need some content in the theads to see it working (or not) . . .

Comment: You have changed your HTML and added another element before the first table. As A Hayworth states, first-child will no longer work, you now need first-of-type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:not` & `:first-of-type` Pseudo-classes on the table and the select it's child `thead` like below example. This will apply the `CSS` to all tables' `thead` except the first.

```css
@media screen {
  .container>:not(table:first-of-type)>thead {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Table Caption</div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>xyz-head</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>xyz-body</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>Table Caption</div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>zxc-head</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>zxc-body</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>Table Caption</div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>esd-head</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>esd-body</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first table is not the first child in the container.

You need first-of-type

```css
.container>table:not(:first-of-type)>thead {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Table Caption</div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>thead1</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
  <div>Table Caption</div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>thead2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
  <div>Table Caption</div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>thead3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Note - I have put in fuller mark up (you need tr and th elements in the thead to see the content selected correctly).